# "Next: Review & Send" button is not displayed correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

After selecting "browse for file" and selecting a file, the "Next: Review & Send" button and the file name occupy the same space.

I was using a clean Safari 7.0.6, but I see the same thing happening in Firefox 32.0.2 (+Firebug).

See the bottom of the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This seems to be the offending bit:

```
<a class="btn _large test-apply-useresume" href="/cv/widgets/review?jobId=90462">Use existing resume</a>
```

The markup to make it look like a button is actually in a class called 'button', not 'btn'. 'btn' only sets float and margin.

The other problem seems to be that my filename is quite long. You can either truncate it, or move the button out of the way. This would work:

```
bottom: 0;
margin-bottom: 6px;
margin-right: 6px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? And browser details too :)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed.

[image]

Thanks for the report!